# Получить значение по ключу PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Используя API, я получаю ответ из переменной `$result` такого вида:

```
echo $result;

{"result":"success","order_id":100888,"order_number":10}
```

Как корректно из строки выше вытащить эту часть `"order_id":100888` и добавить это к переменной.
На первый взгляд это можно сделать с помощью foreach.

Итог должен быть такой: `delivery_order_id = '100888'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Познакомьтесь подробнее с функцией [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '{"result":"success","order_id":100888,"order_number":10}';

$delivery_order_id = json_decode($json)->order_id;

var_dump( $delivery_order_id );
```

Comment: Я так понимаю эта строка здесь необязательна `var_dump( $delivery_order_id );`, только чтобы визуально показать результат?

Comment: @АлександраКузнецова совершенно верно.

Comment: @KAGG Design похоже нет такой переменной wp_json_decode(), только wp_json_encode().